# split a num list into sublists with consecutive numbers

Tags: python, list, numbers, nested-lists

I want to group numbers in a numeric list into sublists. In the sublists must be the consecutive numbers

**input** ==> `[-4,-3,-2,0,1,3,5,6,7,17,18,30]`
**output** ==> `[[-4,-3,-2],[0,1],[3],[5,6,7],[17,18],[30]]`

Preferably without libraries (only the generics)

Comment: You can do it without libraries with one pass

Answer (score 3):

Generators can be good for this sort of thing.

### Code

```
def group_me(list):
    list.sort()
    sublist = []

    while list:
        v = list.pop(0)

        if not sublist or sublist[-1] in [v, v-1]:
            sublist.append(v)
        else:
            yield sublist
            sublist = [v]

    if sublist:
        yield sublist


list = [-4, -3, -2, 0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 17, 18, 30]
result = [sublist for sublist in group_me(list)]
print(result)
```

### Output

```
[[-4, -3, -2], [0, 1], [3], [5, 6, 7], [17, 18], [30]]
```

### Notes

If there are duplicates in the input list, it puts them into the same sublist.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you can simply use a for loop. One pass is the best we can do - we have to look at each element once. This is O(n) in [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Remember that the list must be sorted, otherwise it will not work.

### Code:

```
inpt = [-4,-3,-2,0,1,3,5,6,7,17,18,30]

rv = []

# Set up current list with first element of input
curr = [inpt[0]]

# For each remaining element:
for x in inpt[1:]:
    # If the next element is not 1 greater than the last seen element
    if x - 1 != curr[-1]:
        # Append the list to the return variable and start a new list
        rv.append(curr)
        curr = [x]
    # Otherwise, append the element to the current list.
    else:
        curr.append(x)
rv.append(curr)
```

### Output:

```
>>> rv
[[-4, -3, -2], [0, 1], [3], [5, 6, 7], [17, 18], [30]]
```

Answer (score 1):

two pointer solution

```
a = [-4,-3,-2,0,1,3,5,6,7,17,18,30]
slow, fast = 0,0
ans, temp = [], []
while fast < len(a):
    if fast - slow == a[fast] - a[slow]:
        temp.append(a[fast])
        fast += 1
    else:
        slow = fast
        ans.append(temp)
        temp = []
if fast > slow:
    ans.append(temp)
print(ans)
```